# How to fix the undefined instance echarts in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts

Here's the code:

```
<div echarts [options]="alertTday$ | async" style="max-height: 289px" (chartInit)="onChartInit(barCharts.line, $event)"></div>
```

**TS**

```
  onChartInit(chart: object, instance: any) {
    chart['instance'] = instance;
  }
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.barCharts.line['instance']);
    console.log(this.barCharts.line);
    // this.barCharts.line.options.instance.setOption(this.barCharts.line.options);
  }
```

[image]

the instance is undefined. I already this to apply this: `this.barCharts.line.options['instance'] or this.barCharts.line['instance']` but the value is undefined. What I'm trying to do here is to update the echarts just like his:
`this.barCharts.line['instance'].setOption or this.barCharts.line.options['instance'].setOption` but it doesn't work because the instance is undefined.
ERROR for `this.barCharts.line['instance'].setOption or this.barCharts.line.options['instance'].setOption` 
***Cannot read property 'setOption' of undefined***

Comment: Why don't you just add `this.barCharts.line.options.instance.setOption(this.barCharts.line.options);` to `onChartInit` ?

Comment: @David when updating the chart? it will automatically update?

Comment: I don't know echarts, but your problem is that in `ngAfterViewInit`, `barChar.lines.instance` is not set yet, as `onChartInit` has not been called yet as this point